# drop columns according to header value ()

Tags: pandas, multi-index, drop

I have this dataframe with multiple headers

```
name,   00590BL,    01090BL,    01100MS,    02200MS
lat,    613297, 626278, 626323, 616720
long,   5185127,    5188418,    5188431,    5181393
elv,    1833,   1915,   1915,   1499
1956-01-01, 1,  2,  2,  -2
1956-01-02, 2,  3,  3,  -1
1956-01-03, 3,  4,  4,  0
1956-01-04, 4,  5,  5,  1
1956-01-05, 5,  6,  6,  2
```

I read this as

```
dfr      =  pd.read_csv(f_name,
                            skiprows     = 0,
                            header       = [0,1,2,3], 
                            index_col    = 0,
                            parse_dates  = True
                            )
```

I would like to remove the columns 01090BL, 01100MS. The idea, in the main program, is to have a list of the columns that i want to remove and then drop them. I have, consequently, done as follow:

```
2bremoved = ['01090BL', '01100MS']

dfr = dfr.drop(2bremoved, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but I get the following error:

```
PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
  obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4906: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I have thus done the following:

```
aa = dfr.drop(2bremoved, axis=1, inplace=True,level = 0)
```

but I get an empty dataframe. What am I missing?
thanks

Comment: It's empty because you used `inplace=True` and then assigned that result. You should not use both `inplace` and assignment -- only one or the other. I suggest assigning the result, as [`inplace` will be deprecated/removed in future versions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: Also I don't understand how you named the list `2bremoved`. That's not a legal variable name in python.

Comment: it is a list. Now it seems working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `inplace=True` when assigning the output, also a variable name cannot start with a digit in python:

```
to_remove = ['01090BL', '01100MS']

aa = dfr.drop(to_remove, axis=1, level=0)
```

Output:

```
name       00590BL 02200MS
lat         613297  616720
long       5185127 5181393
elv           1833    1499
1956-01-01       1      -2
1956-01-02       2      -1
1956-01-03       3       0
1956-01-04       4       1
1956-01-05       5       2
```